# Click One Report Viewer Error

Tags: c#

I set

```
Microsoft System CLR Types for sql server 2012 x86 
Microsoft System CLR Types for sql server 2012 x64
```

as prerequisites upon Click Once deployment. It seems to work fine on x64 machines but it crashes on x32 bit machines with the following message below. Was wondering how do I fix this?

Component Microsoft CLR types for sql server 2012 x64 has failed to install with the following error message:
"This installation package is not supported by this processor type. Contact your product vendor."

The following components were sucessfully installed:
Microsoft System CLR Types for sql server 2012 x86

The following components were not installed:
Microsoft report viewer 2012 runtime

The following components failed o install:
Microsoft System CLR Types for sql server 2012 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong package if you just want to display reports from a C# application. The easiest way of deploying the report viewer components is to include them with your ClickOnce deployment.

Go to the deployment settings and turn to the "Application files" tab and switch the deployment status to "Include" for the assemblies starting with "Microsoft.Report*".

[image]

Please note I'm using a German Visual Studio - the labels I quoted above may actually be named differently.

Comment: I do have those set to be "Include"

Comment: Well, then you're fine without anything else, aren't you? You shouldn't have to change anything the project prerequisites. At least I've never done so.

Comment: Would I still require the CLR Types?

Comment: Thanks bud, pulled me out of a jam

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to install a 64bit application on a 32bit machine. check what the machine is running prior to installing, and then set the applications required up for install.

This is how you can check what type the machine is running from C#

```
static bool is64BitProcess = (IntPtr.Size == 8);
static bool is64BitOperatingSystem = is64BitProcess || InternalCheckIsWow64();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool IsWow64Process(
    [In] IntPtr hProcess,
    [Out] out bool wow64Process
);

public static bool InternalCheckIsWow64()
{
    if ((Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 5 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 1) ||
        Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
    {
        using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        {
            bool retVal;
            if (!IsWow64Process(p.Handle, out retVal))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way for the installer to check? The Processor type will always be different.